# Suppose that a triangle T on a unit sphere has area equal to π/2. Which of the following is necessarily true?

Tags: spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

Suppose that a triangle T on a unit sphere has area equal to π/2. Which of the following is necessarily true?

```
A) Each of its angles are equal to π/2.
B) Its height is π/2 and its base has length 2. 
C) It has a vertex at the North Pole.
D) The sum of its internal angles is 3π/2.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is D), by gauss bonnet, all the others are false.

Comment: To quibble: (A) and (C) are only _sometimes_ false. `:-)` Hi Igor, I hadn't known that you are on Math.SE! Welcome.